Routing of own extension fails for detail-page
I’m struggling with a routing problem. I’ve added a slug-field to the TCA and added the configuration to the config.yaml. In the frontend the urls are generated correctly but when I click on the Link the default 404 error page shows up.
This is the routeEnhancer in the config.yaml
  TracepartsDetail:
    type: Extbase
    extension: Traceparts
    plugin: Api
    limitToPages:
      - 348
      - 569
      - 429
      - 472
      - 473
      - 475
    routes:
      - routePath: '/api/{product_slug}'
        _controller: 'Traceparts::show'
        _arguments:
          product_slug: product
    defaultController: 'Traceparts::index'
    aspects:
      product_slug:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: tx_traceparts_domain_model_product
        routeFieldName: path_segment

And this is the fluid template.
<f:link.action action="show" controller="Traceparts" extensionName="Traceparts" pluginName="Api" arguments="{product:product.repositoryProduct.uid}">{product.apiProduct.title}</f:link.action>

If I change the routeFieldName to “uid” everything works fine.
Any idea whats wrong? Or at least how to debug?
Kind regards, Cornel

Looks good to me. Your new column is correctly configured, loaded, has valid values, is filled, etc. Caches emptied?
A quick way to get some more background information for 404 is to add a corresponding output in the template (via ErrorHandling:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/ErrorHandling/Index.html#error-handling)

You need to use the mapped argument name for the aspect:
  TracepartsDetail:
    type: Extbase
    extension: Traceparts
    plugin: Api
    limitToPages:
      - 348
      - 569
      - 429
      - 472
      - 473
      - 475
    routes:
      - routePath: '/api/{product_slug}'
        _controller: 'Traceparts::show'
        _arguments:
          product_slug: product
    defaultController: 'Traceparts::index'
    aspects:
      # mapped argument name, not the placeholder name
      product:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: tx_traceparts_domain_model_product
        routeFieldName: path_segment

